# PySide: QWebView: why a lot of elements are null?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside

Why a lot of QWebElements in a QWebView are `Null`? Though they seem perfectly valid in html.

Here's a demonstration using PySide:

```
from PySide.QtGui import QWidget, QMainWindow, QApplication, QVBoxLayout,\
  QLineEdit, QPainter, QPen
from PySide.QtCore import QUrl, Qt
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebElement
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.lineedit_search = QLineEdit()
    self.lineedit_search.editingFinished.connect(self.loadBrowser)
    self.lineedit_search.setText("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top")
    self.browser = MouseSensitiveWebView()
    self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top"))
    layout.addWidget(self.lineedit_search)
    layout.addWidget(self.browser)
    layout_widget = QWidget()
    layout_widget.setLayout(layout)
    self.setCentralWidget(layout_widget)

  def loadBrowser(self):
    txt = self.lineedit_search.text()
    self.browser.load(QUrl(txt))


class MouseSensitiveWebView(QWebView):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MouseSensitiveWebView, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setMouseTracking(True)
    self._hover_rect = None
    self._hit_elem = None

  def mouseMoveEvent(self, mme):
    mouse_pos = mme.pos()
    hit_test_result = self.page().mainFrame().hitTestContent(mouse_pos)
    if hit_test_result:
      new_rect = hit_test_result.boundingRect()
      if new_rect == self._hover_rect: # don't repaint unless the hovered element changed
        return
      hit_elem = hit_test_result.element()
      if hit_elem.isNull():
        print("{0} is Null".format(hit_elem))
      else:
        print("{0} is not Null".format(hit_elem))
      self._hover_rect = new_rect  
      self._hit_elem = hit_elem
      self.repaint()
    else:
      self._hover_rect = None

  def paintEvent(self, pe):
    if not self._hover_rect:
      super(MouseSensitiveWebView, self).paintEvent(pe)
    else:
      super(MouseSensitiveWebView, self).paintEvent(pe)
      # get the current horizontal and vertical scroll bar positions
      main_frame = self.page().mainFrame()
      hor_pos, ver_pos = main_frame.scrollBarValue(Qt.Horizontal), main_frame.scrollBarValue(Qt.Vertical)
      # move the hover rect by these values
      hover_rect = self._hover_rect
      hover_rect.moveTop(hover_rect.top() - ver_pos)
      hover_rect.moveLeft(hover_rect.left() - hor_pos)
      painter = QPainter(self)
      pen = QPen(Qt.red)
      pen.setWidth(2)
      painter.setPen(pen)
      painter.drawRect(hover_rect)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  main = Window()
  main.setGeometry(50, 50, 800, 600)
  main.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Just keep hovering your mouse and a red square will be drawn around the element you are hovering. If it's null or not, it'll logged to the console.

You'll notice that most of the visible elements are actually `Null`. Which makes the `QWebView` much less useful when operating on the page elements. This also applies to `PyQt4` which seems similar in that respect or event worse and getting more Nulls.

Comment: Did you try to write directly in C++ and Qt and check whether the problem is in the bindings or the library itself?

Comment: @Bakuriu: hmmm, seems like a nice suggestion, I'll try that.

Comment: To me it seems everything that is text comes out as null in your example.

Comment: @Trilarion: if that is true, then could it be a bug in Qt, which should be hit testing the surrounding elements?.

Comment: @Trilarion: that was a nice hint, and it could actually be the answer. if I use `enclosingBlockElement()` instead of `element()` on the hit test result, I never get a null printed. But this skips over all inline elements, like `<a>, <span>`, which I can't get under the mouse now.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Hope you can find a workaround. If you do please post as answer. :)

Comment: @Bakuriu: I've converted it to C++ and confirmed that results are the same, so it's not a binding issue. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the issue of null elements seems to have been filed as a [bug](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtwebkit/commit/4ff43880b4f6dcb4e1f3d8d38b32a96da2b80c6c) recently.

I've made a little workaround that'll allow only links (`<a>` elements), from the inline family, to be selected. I get their text and search within the enclosing parent for an element with that text:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, mme):
    mouse_pos = mme.pos()
    hit_test_result = self.page().mainFrame().hitTestContent(mouse_pos)
    if hit_test_result:
      new_rect = hit_test_result.boundingRect()
      if new_rect == self._hover_rect: # don't repaint unless the hovered element changed
        return
      hit_elem = hit_test_result.element()
      if hit_elem.isNull():
        enclosing = hit_test_result.enclosingBlockElement()
        elem_text = hit_elem.linkText() # works only for <a> elements
        for subelement in enclosing.findAll('*'):
          if subelement.toPlainText() == elem_text:
            print "Found Link {}".format(subelement)
            break
        else:
          print("Element is null and not a link")
      else:
        print("{0} is not Null".format(hit_elem))
      self._hover_rect = new_rect  
      self._hit_elem = hit_elem
      self.repaint()
    else:
      self._hover_rect = None
```